# How to fix the code for the snail to have escaped the well in less days

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following problem:

The Snail and the Well A snail falls at the bottom of a 125 cm well. Each day the snail rises 30 cm. But at night, while sleeping, slides 20 cm because the walls are wet. How many days does it take for the snail to escape the well?

This is my variables and code:

```
well_height = 125

daily_distance = 30

nightly_distance = 20

snail_position = 0

days = 0

while snail_position < well_height:
   days += 1
   snail_position += daily_distance - nightly_distance
Print (days)
```

The answer I get is 13, which is wrong, because I calculated it is 11, because on the last day the snail gets out and does not slide back. However, I don't know how to fix the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
well_height = 125
daily_distance = 30
nightly_distance = 20
snail_position = 0
days = 0

while True:
    days += 1
    snail_position += daily_distance
    if snail_position >= well_height:
        break
    snail_position -= nightly_distance
print(days)
```

The answer I got was 11.

You have to keep in mind that the snail only slides back if it does not reach the well on the current day. Because of this, we **only** add the `daily_distance` before we check the position. Afterwards, if the snail did not make it, we add the nightly distance.

As well, I assume that if the snail reaches the distance of `well_height` that it has completed it's journey. Therefore, I've changed the logic from `snail_position > well_height` to `snail_position >= well_height`.

Comment: @FFF No problem! If you found it helpful, you can mark this answer correct. By doing so, you will help other Stack Overflow members easily find the answer to questions similar to this.